# Shopware 6 - Change Fill-Color of "Add to Wishlist Icon"

Tags: shopware, shopware6

we´d like to change the fill-color of the wishlist-icons. If you click on it the hearth zooms and a color get filled.
We found this attribute in the sourcecode of the shop but couldn´t find a twig-file for this:

How to change the "fill-attribute"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override it by your own color https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-styling

```scss
.product-wishlist {
  .icon-wishlist {
     color: $yourThemeColor;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I mean the "fill-attribute". To change the color of the hearth is easy. But if you click on the hearth it makes an zoom-effect and the hearth gets filled by an color. Your CSS just changes the outline of the hearth.

Comment: @Datastorm1989 I added the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding the `color` property by adding custom `CSS` to the icon.

Comment: No, I´m not sure about your comment. I mean the "fill-attribute". To change the color of the hearth is easy. But if you click on the hearth it makes an zoom-effect and the hearth gets filled by an color. Your CSS just changes the outline of the hearth.